# Odd results when testing boolean variable within $.getJSON function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am having a problem I can't seem to wrap my brain around, and as I can't find any other examples of this sort of example online, I have turned (once again) to this fine community.

I will not overcomplicate this question by stating everything that this function (and many others) are designed to do when working together, however, I will say that this function (eventDayPlotter) is repeated for every day of the month. I don't understand the results contained within the following snippet.

```
function eventDayPlotter(day, gridMod, monthAdjust)
{
    //Beginning of event day plotting.
    isAnEvent = false;

    $.getJSON("/JsonControl/Events.json", function (jsonObj) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.events.length; ++i) 
        {
            if(day == jsonObj.events[i].dateNumber && (navDate.getMonth() + monthAdjust) == (jsonObj.events[i].dateMonth -1) && navDate.getFullYear() == jsonObj.events[i].dateYear)
            {
                document.getElementById("cGrid" + gridMod).className="eventDay";
                console.log(jsonObj.events[i].title)
                document.getElementById("cGrid" + gridMod).onmousedown = function(){document.getElementById("eventBox").src="/Event htms/Event.htm"; document.getElementById("eventBox").document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = jsonObj.events[i].title;}
                isAnEvent = true;
            }
        }
    });
    if(isAnEvent == true)
    {
        console.log("true")
    }
    if(isAnEvent == false)
    {
        console.log("false")
    }
}
```

**The Results of console.log (in its entirety)**

```
33false _main.js:1708
Okmulgee Public Schools County Professional Day _main.js:1696
Okmulgee Public Schools Starts 3rd Quarter _main.js:1696
Okmulgee Public Schools-Closed in Observance of Martin Luther King Jr. Holiday
```

The first if branch, I do expect, to be executed 3 times, and it is, however, as you can see, once the diagnostic if branches (the branches with the console.logs) are outside of the $.getJSON function (where they will logically need to be, once they contain meaningful content) isAnEvent is always false. I can't understand that, as it is not out of scope in any way (to my knowledge).

Also, I don't expect the later lines in the file to be logged with console.log first (before the other 3 lines), but it appears this function is executing backwards? I mean, I know that can't be true, but how can this be? I am at an utter loss...

When testing isAnEvent within the first if branch or just outside of it (still within the .getJSON function) its value isn't always what it should be (because that's not where they need to logically go), but it isn't always false either, however, once outside of the .getJSON function, it is always false, even if it was just turned to true.

Clearly there is something going on here that I can't understand.

Lastly, in case it isn't obvious, 3 things:

1)I am grabbing the JSON data just fine, and

2)The first if branch is supposed to set isAnEvent to true if any of the dates from the json file match that date. Then the next time eventDayPlotter is called, it should reset isAnEvent to false and test the next date (passed in with arguments) in the same way.

3)There are no script errors that show in the console.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: `$.getJSON` is **asynchronous**! Put the logging in the callback as well

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. Code following `$.getJSON` will not wait for it to finish.

Comment: Btw, your event handlers lacks a closure for preserving the `i` value, yours will only show the last event on mousedown.

Comment: I wondered that as well but hadn't tested that far. I figured that would be in error too.  I hate the way this code was originally written. It is a logical mess. How could I get it remember what {i} was at the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getJSON()` is asynchronous.  That means that it completes and calls it's completion function some time AFTER `eventDayPlotter()` completes.

Thus, you can only test the value of `isAnEvent` inside the completion function.  You can't test it's value where you are testing it at the end of `eventDayPlotter()`.

---

FYI, you can fix the value of `i` in your event handlers by capturing it in a self-executing function closure like this:

```
function eventDayPlotter(day, gridMod, monthAdjust)
{
    //Beginning of event day plotting.
    isAnEvent = false;

    $.getJSON("/JsonControl/Events.json", function (jsonObj) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.events.length; ++i) 
        {
            if(day == jsonObj.events[i].dateNumber && (navDate.getMonth() + monthAdjust) == (jsonObj.events[i].dateMonth -1) && navDate.getFullYear() == jsonObj.events[i].dateYear)
            {
                document.getElementById("cGrid" + gridMod).className="eventDay";
                console.log(jsonObj.events[i].title)
                (function(index) {
                    document.getElementById("cGrid" + gridMod).onmousedown = function(){document.getElementById("eventBox").src="/Event htms/Event.htm"; document.getElementById("eventBox").document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = jsonObj.events[index].title;}
                })(i);
                isAnEvent = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I see, well there isn't any way to make it wait, is there?

Comment: @VoidKing - The "A" in AJAX stands for Asynchronous.  There are sometimes ways to make it synchronous (so it would wait for completion), but they are not recommended because they lock up the browser during the request and are generally a bad user experience.

Comment: @VoidKing - not meaning to rub it in.  I added more info to my previous comment.

Comment: @VoidKing technically you can make it wait, however it is not a good practice.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's okay, I was really just poking fun at myself for not remembering that. I'm still relatively new (or very new compared to the professionals on this site, I'm sure)

Comment: @jfriend00 One more question if I may. As Bergi pointed out in his comment on my question, {Btw, your event handlers lacks a closure for preserving the i value, yours will only show the last event on mousedown. – Bergi 4 mins ago}, How can I get the mousedown to remember what 'i' was at the time it was plotted. Could I just plot it as string?

Comment: @VoidKing - I added an example for how you can fix the index `i` in your event handler with a self-executing function closure.  This essentially passes the value `i` to a self-executing function and it is then captured as the argument to that function where a separate copy of the function closure is preserved for each event handler you create in that `for` loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 So when you append (i) after the functions closing bracket in your example, that makes it self executing? Wherein 'i' being the index reference (as used in the main function) is passed as an argument to the function itself?

Comment: @jfriend00 I can't seem to get the code you provided to work. I wonder what I am doing wrong. I have it just as you do above, except that I've changed .getJSON to .ajax and set asynchronous to false, to solve the original problem.

Comment: @VoidKing - I'd suggest checking for script errors in the browser console.  I can't really help further without seeing your exact code in action.  It's possible my code has an error in it, but I can't execute it to see.  Or, it's possible there is something else wrong with your code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Very possible, indeed.  Thanks for all of your help!